# Investigating different datatypes in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, csv, import, casting, pandas

I have 4 files which I want to read with Python / Pandas, the files are: https://github.com/kelsey9649/CS8370Group/tree/master/TaFengDataSet
I stripped away the first row (column titles in chinese) in all 4 files.
But other from that, the 4 files are supposed to have the same format.

Now I want to read them and merge into one big DataFrame. I tried it by using

```
pars = {'sep':          ';',
            'header':       None,
            'names':        ['date','customer_id','age','area','prod_class','prod_id','amount','asset','price'], 
            'parse_dates':  [0]}

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in ('01', '02', '12', '11'):
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(cfg.abspath+'D'+i,**pars))
```

BUT: The file D11 gives me a different format of the single columns and thus cannot be merged properly. The file contains like over 200k lines and thus I cannot easily look for the problem in that file but as mentioned above, I was assuming it has the same format, but obviously there's some small difference in the format.

What's the easiest way of now investigating into the problem? Obviously, I cannot check every single line in that file...

When I read the 3 working files and merge them; and read D11 independetly, the line

```
A = pd.read_csv(cfg.abspath+'D11',**pars)
```

still gives me the following warning:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:1130: DtypeWarning: Columns (
1,4,5,6,7,8) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=
False.
  data = self._reader.read(nrows)
```

Using the method `.info()` in pandas (for `A` and `df`) yields:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 594119 entries, 0 to 178215
Data columns (total 9 columns):
date           594119 non-null datetime64[ns]
customer_id    594119 non-null int64
age            594119 non-null object
area           594119 non-null object
prod_class     594119 non-null int64
prod_id        594119 non-null int64
amount         594119 non-null int64
asset          594119 non-null int64
price          594119 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(6), object(2)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 223623 entries, 0 to 223622
Data columns (total 9 columns):
date           223623 non-null object
customer_id    223623 non-null object
age            223623 non-null object
area           223623 non-null object
prod_class     223623 non-null object
prod_id        223623 non-null object
amount         223623 non-null object
asset          223623 non-null object
price          223623 non-null object
```

Even if I would use the dtype-option on import, I would somehow still be scared of wrong/bad results as there might happen some wrong casting of datatypes while importing!?

How to overcome and solve the issue?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a problem that is too boring to be done by hand, the solution is to write a program:

```
for col in ('age', 'area'):
    for i, val in enumerate(A[col]):
        try:
            int(val)
        except:
            print('Line {}: {} = {}'.format(i, col, val))
```

This will show you all the lines in the file with non-integer values in the `age` and `area` columns. This is the first step in debugging the problem. Once you know what the problematic values are, you can better decide how to deal with them -- maybe by pre-processing (cleaning) the data file, or by using some pandas code to select and fix the problematic values.

Comment: Yeah that helped me with it, thanks. But I had to implement it the other way around as I needed to check the integer columns (age and area actually are (when correctly provided) characters/strings).